# Use Lucene field to boost document score without using field value for selecting

Tags: lucene

I have a query where I want to use a certain field to boost the score of the document if a match is found but without actually selecting the document.

So if I have 
document 1
id:foo
smoke:true
city:Amsterdam

document 2
id:to
smoke:false
city:Amsterdam

document 3
id:bar
smoke:true
city:Rotterdam

I would like to select all documents where +smoke:true but where Amsterdam results are ranked higher.

I thought of doing
+smoke:true city:Amsterdam^1.5

but I found that in that case documents are also selected where smoke:false and city=Amsterdam.

Comment: Your query should have worked -- a mandatory term must appear in the result. There's probably something wrong with you query parsing.

Comment: The point is not that +smoke:true is not being honoured, the point is that I want to use a boost factor but prevent the boosted variable from being treated as an OR city:Amsterdam. If none of the other conditions are true, Amsterdam should not be selected at all.